# Unable to make abstract member with a pointer to itself in the parameter

Tags: c++, polymorphism, abstract-class, virtual

I need help. How can I get something like this to work?

```
// main.cpp

class A {
public:
    virtual void foo(A* a) = 0;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void foo(B* b);
};

void B::foo(B* b) {
    //...
};

int main() {
    B object;
        // clang++: error - variable type 'B' is an abstract class
}
```

In my code, the compiler warns that foo is still pure within class B, and therefore class B is abstract and cannot be instantiated.

B::foo needs to have B* as a parameter, not just any class derived from A.

How can I fix this?

Comment: If `foo` in the derived class requires a `B*`, but it requires a `A*` in the base, then how can the former be overriding the latter? This doesn't work regardless of abstractness. `foo` in `B` should take a `A*`. Why do you want it to take a `B*`? How do you expect to use the `foo` function on e.g. a `A*` pointer?

Comment: I think this has more to do with showing something to do with the choice of your design.
What kind of thing are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

The signature of a virtual function in the derived must be the same as in the base (except for covariant return type, which is not relevant to this case).

So you must have the same function in B (otherwise B doesn't implement the pure virutal function declared by its base, and would thus be abstract by himself). So for B not to be abstract you need:

```
class B : public A {
public:
    void foo(A* a) override; // the override here is a bonus
                             // it would work without it
                             // but it helps by getting compilation error
                             // in case the signature doesn't correspond
                             // an exiting virtual function in the base
};
```

But then you may decide that this function allows only an actual B to be sent to it, if called with B. In which case you may implement it as:

```
class B : public A {
public:
    // user calling this function must send a pointer to an actual B object
    void foo(A* a) override {
        B& other = dynamic_cast<B&>(*a); // would throw bad_cast if not a B
        // ... rest of your code, work with 'other' as B&
    }
};
```

It may be a bit questionable if this is a good design choice. But it is doable.